# Difference in derivative between $\frac{6}{3x^2+1}$ and $\frac{6}{3x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Is there a difference in derivative between $\frac{6}{3x^2+1}$ and $\frac{6}{3x^2}$ I thought there wouldn't be and I've asked several people all with different results?

Comment: Yes there is a difference because you have to square the denominator in the end.

Comment: thats the only difference?

Comment: In this case yes. Try it, and write the answer here.

Comment: I was using this one as an example, the ones I'm using are multivariable partial derivates, which use the same rules. I'm just wondering if there is a general rule for the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$,

Clearly there is difference in derivative between these two functions.

Can you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = \frac{6}{3x^2+1}$$
Then we have

$$\tag{1}f'(x) = \frac{d/dx(6)\cdot(3x^2+1)-6\cdot d/dx(3x^2+1)}{(3x^2+1)^2} = \frac{-6\cdot6x}{(3x^2+1)^2}$$

Since $\frac{d}{dx} ~3x^2+1 = \frac{d}{dx}~ 3x^2$ there is no difference upstairs in $(1)$, but only in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

rewriting the terms as $6(3x^2+1)^{-1}$ we get $-6(3x^2+1)^{-2}(6x)$
and
         $2x^{-2}$ gives the derivative as $-4x^{-3}$